# How to test service object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have written the service object below.

```
class LeadGeneration
  def initialize contact_id
    @lead = Lead.find_or_initialize_by(contact_id: contact_id)
  end

  def lead
    @lead
  end

  def activate_lead
    lead.active!
  end

  def stale_lead
     lead.stale!
  end
end
```

I am a little confused on how exactly to test it. I have written the spec below

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe LeadGeneration do
    let(:contact) { FactoryGirl.create(:contact) }

 it "#activate_lead" do
    lg = LeadGeneration.new(contact.id)
    expect(lg.lead).to receive(:active!)
    lg.activate_lead
  end

  it "#stale_lead" do
    lg = LeadGeneration.new(contact.id)
    expect(lg.lead).to receive(:stale!)
    lg.stale_lead
  end
end
```

This spec works fine, but I would like to do it without exposing the lead that is generated. How exactly do I go about this. I could use

```
expect(Lead.any_instance).to receive(:active!)
```

But from my reading this is bad practice. Any thoughts?

Comment: what do you mean: "This spec works fine, but I would like to do it **without exposing the lead that is generated**. How exactly do I go about this"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in this instance all you're testing is that the lead object receives messages, you can stub `#lead` to return a mock object that you set expectations on:

```
it "#activate_lead" do
  lead = double('lead')
  lg = LeadGeneration.new(contact.id)
  # make #lead return our test double whenever it's called
  allow(lg).to receive(:lead) { lead }
  # our test double should receive the message
  expect(lead).to receive(:active!)
  lg.activate_lead
end
```

This means you could move the `#lead` method into a private/protected space, since you don't have to call it directly anymore.

Comment: So is this the standard practice when you want to make objects like 'lead' private? Thx

Comment: I wouldn't say that this solution is a "standard practice", since the solution I posted is specific to your test case. It's standard practice to only make the public methods that you need to make, and then leave the rest private, and then only test your public interface (never call private methods directly). In _this_ case, that's achieved by stubbing `#lead`. It's also good practice to isolate unit tests, which this solution does by removing the dependency on the `Lead` class.